# Executing an R notebook via papermill in a separate Python notebook

Tags: python, r, jupyter-notebook, conda, papermill

I have a notebook using a `custom_python` kernel that calls papermill to execute an another notebook which uses a `conda_r_custom_r` kernel. When I run the following

```
import papermill as pm

pm.execute_notebook(
    'my-r-notebook.ipynb',
    output_path=None,
    parameters=dict(param=4),
    kernel_name='conda_r_custom_r',
    language='R'
)
```

I get an error `NoSuchKernel: No such kernel named conda_r_custom_r`. I'm running this on an AWS SageMaker instance where I've created a bunch of custom environments.